# How to play audio on Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a mini addon for chrome. In the addon, I have inserted a code to play audio where ajax is success. It doesn't work with websites that use `https`, but works fine on websites that use `http`. Can you help me edit it.

`manifest.json`

[image]

`mystyle.js`

[image]

For full resolution of the images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8F5Q.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bX5I.png

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, there are two issues with your code:

1. You shouldn't put `chrome.tabs.getSelected` and `chrome.browserAction` in `mystyle.js`. `mystyle.js` is a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), which can only access limited chrome api.

   > However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
   >
   > - Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
   >
   >   - extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest ,
   >       sendRequest )
   >   - i18n
   >   - runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage )
   >   - storage
   > - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
   > - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts
2. You can't send http request from a https web page, since it's restricted by SOP and it's a browser behavior. To solve this, you should move your http request logic to background page and add the server url to permissions, see my following answer for more info.

   [Chrome extension - Disable Blocking of Mixed Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348559/chrome-extension-disable-blocking-of-mixed-content/36350189#36350189)